# Why do I have to use bash -l -c inside my container?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

I've created a docker container using the following Dockerfile (truncated):

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04
# curl enables downloading of other things
RUN apt-get install curl -y
# download and install rvm...
RUN \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
# ... so that we can install ruby
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm requirements"
```

And so on.

This all works, but the problem I have is how / where the packages are installed.

If I just run rvm using `docker run [...] rvm` I get "Unable to locate rvm", but if I run `docker run [...] /bin/bash -l -c "rvm"` it works. (I found the "-l -c" options online, but have no idea what they do, and can't find a satisfactory explanation of what I'm doing!)

This isn't a docker question - it's a bash / *nix question - I presume there's something about how / where things are installed, possibly related to running the install under root?

Just to be clear - I want to be able to run the things that I install direct from the CLI.

**EDIT 1**

Installing Ruby using rvm is the recommended method, however if you want to run things in a non-interactive, non-login shell (i.e. within a docker container), this just causes too much hassle with paths and environment variables and login scripts not running.

Given that I am using this to run a docker container, which by definition is isolated, and recoverable (just build another one), I don't really care about switching versions, or isolating packages, and so I've decided to install Ruby from a package repo (http://brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/) instead. This 'just works'.

It may not work for you - I am only installing Ruby in order to get the Foreman gem, as I am running an app through a Procfile, so I'm not that fussed about the details, I just need it to work. If you're building a Ruby app, I wouldn't follow my advice.

My Dockerfile is here, FWIW, https://index.docker.io/u/yunojuno/dev/

Comment: you should include output from `type -ap rvm` and `echo $PATH`

Comment: Adding `CMD ["bash", "-l"]` to your Dockerfile will also work.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From [`bash(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

- `-l` Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell
- `-c` If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.

You're running the command passed to the `-c` argument. `-l` makes it a login shell so bash first reads `/etc/profile`, which probably has the path to `rvm` which is what makes it work.

FWIW, here's what I do to install `rvm` in a docker container.

```
# Install some dependencies
RUN apt-get -y -q install curl rubygems

# Install rvm
RUN curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

# Install package dependencies
RUN /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm requirements

# Install ruby
RUN /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm install ruby-2.0.0

# create first wrapper scripts
RUN /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm wrapper ruby-2.0.0 myapp rake rails gem
```

Comment: Yup - that's it - thanks. If I run `docker run [...] bash -l` from the host I get into the container with a shell that works - env vars set etc. So it's getting the commands to run within an login shell when I pass them in to the docker run command that's my challenge.

Comment: Perhaps it's just sys admin habit, but I usually like to give fully qualified paths to everything. That way you (hopefully) know what you're running.

Comment: Yup - that's what I've just done - you beat me to it. And I guess that since the key to Docker is repeatability and reuse, I don't need to worry about things not being where they should be - as they will always be in exactly the same place they were last time.

Comment: Of course - now I'm getting ruby errors: /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory

Comment: If I do this and try to do RUN gem, then I get a error gem not found. IMHO it's easier to remember the /bin/bash -l -c "" rather than trying to remember the paths of where everything else.