# Run a shell command inside a running Docker container using Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I want to execute shell commands, for eg: a "wget" command inside a running docker container using Ansible. This is the playbook I am trying to execute

```
---

- name: Enter into a running container and run a command
  docker_container:
    name: centos_conatainer
    state: started
    image: centos
    command: wget https://downloadlink.com
```

This stops the container and also it is not downloading the file. Is this the right way to execute shell commands using docker_container module, or is there any other way to do this using Ansible?

Comment: This is bad practice and not a good way to use Docker. You should probably rethink how you use Docker or use a VM.

That said, Michael answers your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Command Inside of Docker Container Using Ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878795/run-command-inside-of-docker-container-using-ansible)

Comment: Re: duplicate, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41626257/1347604) from the other question describes another approach to this same problem using _docker_ connection introduced in Ansible 2.0 and the _raw_ module that isn't covered here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the Ansible equivalent of the *docker exec* command-line.

*Command* in ansible docker_container is the equivalent of  the command option in the *docker run* command-line.

It doesn't appear that this new Ansible module has support for this.  You'll just have to use the generic Ansible command.

Example:

```
- name: Enter into a running container and run a command
  command: docker exec centos_container wget https://downloadlink.com
```

Comment: Small change, I used this command `docker exec -i "{{ container_name}}" /bin/bash -c 'command to execute '`

Comment: Nowadays there is the --connection=docker option to do that. You still need python inside your docker container. If you can't, you can still use the [`raw` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/raw_module.html), but that's going down a slippery slope... Handle with care.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no way you can do it with `docker_container` module – it is used to start a new container with the specified command.

I use this code to execute commands inside containers:

```
- name: Execute command inside a container
  shell: "docker exec {{ containerName }} {{ commandToRun }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can accomplish this with an Ansible community collection. To install this, please run:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install community.docker
```

If you successfully installed this collection, you can create the following task:

```
- name: Execute command inside a container
  community.docker.docker_container_exec:
    container: "{{ container_name }}"
    command: /bin/bash -c "echo Hello world"
```

This is equivalent to:

```
docker exec -i "{{ container_name }}" /bin/bash -c "echo Hello world"
```

Answer (score -3):

Entrypoint or CMD can do the job:

https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I want to do it using "ansible_docker" module and not Dockerfile