# How to use Deployer with Docker (Laradock)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laradock, php-deployer, docker-exec

I created a fresh Digital Ocean server with Docker on it (using [Laradock](http://laradock.io)) and got my Laravel website working well.

Now I want to automate my deployments using [Deployer](https://deployer.org).

I think my only problem is that I can't get Deployer to run `docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q php-fpm) bash;`, which is the command I successfully manually use to enter the appropriate Docker container (after using SSH to connect from my local machine to the Digital Ocean server).

When Deployer tries to run it, I get this error message:

```
➤ Executing task execphpfpm
[1.5.6.6] > cd /root/laradock && (pwd;)
[1.5.6.6] < /root/laradock
[1.5.6.6] > cd /root/laradock && (docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q php-fpm) bash;)
[1.5.6.6] < the input device is not a TTY
➤ Executing task deploy:failed
• done on [1.5.6.6]
✔ Ok [3ms]
➤ Executing task deploy:unlock
[1.5.6.6] > rm -f ~/daily/.dep/deploy.lock
• done on [1.5.6.6]
✔ Ok [188ms]

In Client.php line 99:

  [Deployer\Exception\RuntimeException (1)]
  The command "cd /root/laradock && (docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q php-fpm) bash;)" failed.

  Exit Code: 1 (General error)

  Host Name: 1.5.6.6

  ================
  the input device is not a TTY
```

Here are the relevant parts of my `deploy.php`:

```
host('1.5.6.6')
        ->user('root')
        ->identityFile('~/.ssh/id_rsa2018-07-09')
        ->forwardAgent(true)
        ->stage('production')
        ->set('deploy_path', '~/{{application}}');

before('deploy:prepare', 'execphpfpm');

task('execphpfpm', function () {
    cd('/root/laradock');
    run('pwd;');
    run('docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q php-fpm) bash;');
    run('pwd');
});
```

I've already spent a day and a half reading countless articles and trying so many different variations. E.g. replacing the `-it` flag with `-i`, or setting `export COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1` or replacing the whole `docker exec` command with `docker-compose exec php-fpm bash;`.

I expect that I'm missing something fairly simple. Docker is widely used, and Deployer seems popular too.

Comment: So far, I've figured out that instead using `run('cd /root/laradock && (docker exec -it $(docker-compose ps -q php-fpm) bash;)', ['tty' => true]);` leads my `deploy.php` script to successfully switch into the `php-fpm` container but pauses Deployer until I type "exit", at which point it unfortunately switches back out of the `php-fpm` container (and so fails). If I instead use `run('cd /root/laradock && (docker exec -i $(docker-compose ps -q php-fpm) bash;)');`, that command seems to be completely ignored; the dir remains as `/root` at the top level of the server rather than in a container.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878795/run-command-inside-of-docker-container-using-ansible where they use `docker exec container-name bash -l -c` . You can use it to run commands inside the workspace container

Answer (score 1):

To use Laravel Deployer you should connect via ssh directly to the workspace container.

You can expose the container's ssh port:
https://laradock.io/documentation/#access-workspace-via-ssh

Let's say you've forwarded container ssh port 22 to vm port 2222. In that case you need configure your Deployer to use the port 2222.

Also remember to set proper secure SSH keys, not the default ones.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case I had separate containers for PHP and Composer. That is why I could not connect to the container via SSH while deploying.

So I configured the `bin/php` and `bin/composer` parameters like this:

```
set('bin/php', 'docker exec php php');
set('bin/composer', 'docker run --volume={{release_path}}:/app composer');
```

Notice that here we use `exec` for a persistent `php` container which is already running at the moment and `run` to start a new instance of `composer` container which will stop after installing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
docker-compose exec -T php-fpm bash;
```

The -T option will

> Disable pseudo-tty allocation. By default `docker-compose exec` allocates a TTY.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. See my question. `-it` includes the `T` option already.