# Using ansible delegate_to with docker: permission denied

Tags: docker, permissions, ansible

I would like to execute a command inside a container of a machine I manage with ansible.

This is possible with the `delegate_to` command (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41626257/458274):

```
- name: Add container to inventory
  add_host:
    name: mycontainer
    ansible_connection: docker
  changed_when: false

- name: Do something in container
  delegate_to: mycontainer
  raw: echo "hello world"
```

However, the user I'm using has no permission to access `/var/run/docker.sock`. I could fix this by adding the user to the `docker` group, but I feel that this is a bad security practice, since any program running with this user account could now gain root permission without a password.

Using `become` does not work either, since it will be delegated to the container, too.

How can I use `delegate_to`, but switch to another user first?

Comment: I think that if you expect to target containers with your playbook you're going to need to give your local user access to the Docker socket.

Comment: That's a hazard of docker and is plus-or-minus unavoidable (the plus or minus is that you can use an intermediate layer like kubernetes or mesos in order to control what gets scheduled to run on docker); also, if user-A can switch to user-B and user-B can run docker, you're right back where you started from

Comment: You cannot expect to run any commands inside a docker container with the docker connection type without having access to the docker sock (i.e. being able to run docker client commands).

Comment: You could just directly invoke the docker command: `- name: Do something   become: yes    shell: docker exec mycontainer echo "hello world"`. Due to become=yes it will get access to the socket.

Comment: ...and just for the sake of clarity, there's no need to use `delegate_to` to target containers. They can be targeted using the `hosts:` directive in a play just like any other host.

Comment: Why having the user running the playbook rihgts to use Docker should be a bad security practice? If you are switching from the original user to another user and this other user has permissions to use Docker, the security risk is the same: in one situation the original user can use Docker directly, in the second situation the original user can become the other user and use Docker as well - in both cases Docker is accessible by the original user.

Comment: @Pierre B.: Because a password is needed to switch the user. If it happens that the ansible user is running some script (not necessarily at the same time when ansible is being used), this script can easily gain root permissions. A user should always have the least permissions possible, you can never be sure if an attacker might be able to execute code as your ansible user.

Comment: Have you tried `docker run --user {someuser}` or `docker-compose -u {someuser}`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute commands in a container, then you *will* need to provide  some sort of communication with the docker daemon.

Ignoring ansible for a moment, you can talk to the docker daemon in 2 modes:

- via a unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock`
- via a tcp port (defaults to `2375`).

So your alternative, if not using the Unix socket, would be to use the TCP connection. Pick your poison ;-)