# Ansible commands on docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, ansible-2.x

Upto now i had setup my ansible-playbook commands running on AWS EC2 instances.

can i run regular ansible commands like (linefile, apt, pip, etc) on container?

can i add my container-ip to hosts file in container-group and then does the same code works, here if i chanage my main.yml file that has

```
hosts: ec2-group
```

to

```
hosts:contaniers-group
```

does all commands work?

i am bit  beginner into this..please do confirm me i am actually thinking of making docker-compose files from scratch, and run docker-compose commands using ansible.

Comment: Have once done this following the steps suggested in this SO thread.... 
[Run Command Inside of Docker Container Using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41626257/10363259)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can*, but it's not really how Docker is designed to be used.

A Docker *container* is usually a wrapper around a single process.  In the standard setup you create an *image* that has that application built and packaged, and you can just run it without any further setup.  It's not usually interesting to run a bare Linux distribution container (which won't have an application installed) or to run an interactive shell as the main container process.  Tutorials like Docker's [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) walk through this sequence.

A corollary to this is that containers don't usually have any local state.  In the best case any state a container needs is in an external database; if you can't do that then you store local state in a *volume* that outlives the container.

Finally, it's extremely routine to delete and recreate containers.  You need to do this to change some common options; in a cluster environment like Kubernetes this can happen outside your control.  When this happens the new container will restart running its default setup, and it won't know about any manual changes the previous container might have had.

So you don't usually want to try to install software directly in a running container, since that will get lost as soon as the container exits.  You can, in principle, get a shell in a container (via `docker exec`) but this is more of a debugging tool than an administration tool.  You could make the only process a container runs be an ssh daemon, but anything you start this way will get lost as soon as the container exits (and I've never seen a recipe that correctly and securely sets up credentials to access it).

I'd recommend learning the standard Dockerfile system and running self-contained Docker images over trying to adapt Ansible to this rather different environment.