# Dockerfile install ruby rails on rhel7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, dockerfile, rvm

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile to install ruby rails on rhel7. But get this error on rvm. I tried the same steps on local instances and worked fine, but fails via docker build.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7

RUN subscription-manager register --username <user> --password <password> --auto-attach

RUN yum install -y gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel zlib zlib-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel make bzip2 autoconf automake libtool bison iconv-devel sqlite-devel; \
    curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import -; \
    curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg2 --import -; \
    curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable;\
    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh;\
    source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm;\
    rvm reload;\
    rvm install 2.6.1;\
    rvm list;\
    rvm use 2.6.1 --default;\
    gem install rails;\
    ruby --version;\
    rails --version
```

```
  Donate: <code>https://opencollective.com/rvm/donate</code>
/bin/sh: rvm: command not found
/bin/sh: rvm: command not found
/bin/sh: rvm: command not found
/bin/sh: rvm: command not found
/bin/sh: ruby: command not found
error building at step {Env:[PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin container=oci] Command:run Args:[curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import -;     curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg2 --import -;     curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable;    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh;    source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm;    rvm reload;    rvm install 2.6;    rvm list;    rvm use 2.6 --default;    ruby --version] Flags:[] Attrs:map[] Message:RUN curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import -;     curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg2 --import -;     curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable;    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh;    source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm;    rvm reload;    rvm install 2.6;    rvm list;    rvm use 2.6 --default;    ruby --version Original:RUN curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import -;     curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg2 --import -;     curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable;    source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh;    source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm;    rvm reload;    rvm install 2.6;    rvm list;    rvm use 2.6 --default;    ruby --version}: error while running runtime: exit status 127
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I have to use bash -l -c inside my container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895523/why-do-i-have-to-use-bash-l-c-inside-my-container)

Comment: Usually you don’t want to use a version manager like `rvm` in a Docker container.  Since you’re packaging a single application, just install the single version of the Ruby interpreter you need as the system Ruby.