# Docker run Python File on startup

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

First of all, I'm very new to Docker, so if my general idea of how this should work is stupid, then please tell me :)
I created a Dockerfile which looks like this:

```
FROM nodered/node-red:1.2.1
COPY./retrieveNewFlow.py /home/retrieveNewFlow.py
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]
CMD [ "python3", "/home/retrieveNewFlow.py" ]
```

I want to execute the retrieveNewFlow.py Python Script every time the container starts. But I get the following error message:

```
 /usr/bin/python3: /usr/bin/python3: cannot execute binary file
```

Can anybody image what i've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ENTRYSCRIPT` in your `dockerfile`

from `ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]`

to `ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-l", "-c" ]`

Comment: +1. Here is a reference on the why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895523/why-do-i-have-to-use-bash-l-c-inside-my-container

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. But is it possible, that the container stays active, after the python script terminates.

Answer (score 1):

The `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are [combined together into a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), so the main container command becomes

```sh
/bin/bash python3 /home/retrieveNewFlow.py
```

This instructs Bash to try to run the Python interpreter as a shell script; since it's not, you get the error you see.

You are not required to have an `ENTRYPOINT`, and you should remove it here.  Leave the `CMD` as you have it.

```sh
# No ENTRYPOINT
CMD ["python3", "/home/retrieveNewFlow.py"]
```

This will cause the main container command to be the Python script, without unnecessarily introducing a `bash` wrapper.